# How do I use qs.stringify in Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to use qs stringify to encode URL parameters in a Vue Axios call. In my main.js I have the following:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Search from './Search.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import qs from 'qs'

const search = createApp(Search);
search.use(VueAxios, axios, qs);
search.mount('#v_search_app');
```

Then in Search.vue, I have the following:

```
let params = {
  "q": this.q,
  "page": this.page,
  "per_page": this.perPage,
  "filters": { 
    "page": {
      "source_table_enum": this.selectedSources
      "topic_id": this.selectedTopics
    }
  }
}
let queryString = this.qs.stringify(params);
```

This results in the following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stringify')*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Search.vue`, you should do this:

```js
import qs from 'qs'
let queryString = qs.stringify(params)
```

You have to import the library into the component you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946301/2512022)
to properly use the library you will need to install the package in to your project.

To do this:

In the root of your application run the following in your terminal/command line

```
npm install qs
```